# Tomee Jaxrs 1.7.1 + Mojarra 2.29 Memory Leak

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, memory-leaks, apache-tomee

I'm using Tomee, Primefaces 5.0 and Apache SHiro.

When I start the server, it consumes 600 Mb of memory.
If I open and close a certain page, that contains a lot of information, but is related to a ViewScoped bean, the memory usage goes to 1,6 GiB. The same thing if I open other things, even RequestScopped beans.
I have checked and the PreDestroy method is being called, so my problem isn't it.

Using Eclipse Memory Analyser:

> One instance of "org.apache.openejb.core.WebContext" loaded by
>   "org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader @ 0xa34f0cf0" occupies
>   1,189,717,200 (97.83%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one
>   instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]" loaded
>   by "system class loader".
>
> Keywords 
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]
>   org.apache.openejb.core.WebContext
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader @ 0xa34f0cf0

And when I run shutdown.sh, I have the following in catalina.out

> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks SEVERE: The web application [/projeto-bim]
>   created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext.InheritableThreadLocalMap] (value
>   [org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext$InheritableThreadLocalMap@5720d785])
>   and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value
>   [{org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext_SECURITY_MANAGER_KEY=org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager@2d258973,
>   org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext_SUBJECT_KEY=org.apache.shiro.web.subject.support.WebDelegatingSubject@7b62f42c}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak.

I tried several things, like setting some configuration in web.xml to maintain only one session or set Tomee to save session information on disk, but nothing worked.

What should I do?

// New information:
The memory goes to 1.6 GiB and stops because that is my maximum heap space. The web server begins to throw OutOfMemoryError. I'll try to increase this to see how much more it uses.

Ok. Now I increased the java heap space to 3 GB. And my application uses it all. It is clearly a memory leak, because each time I open a certain page, which contains a lot of information, the memory goes up 300 Mb, and it never decreases!
What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much thing linked to any leaks.

WebContext is bound to your webapp in TomEE (normal you see it while your app is running)

then all warnings are just that apache shiro is in your webapp and uses threadlocal to keep security context by thread. Since it was loaded by the webapp it can creates leaks but excepting patching shiro you can't help it.

Comment: So the report from Eclipse memory analyser is just a false positive? Is it normal to a web application like this consume more than two gigabytes of memory?

Comment: No no, what I said is the data of your original post doesn't help to diagonstic the leak you see.